# Find value of all functions with trace active

Tags: r, debugging, trace

How can I find the value of all the functions for which I have activated `trace`?  I know I can turn of the global `tracingState`, but I find that I forget which functions are being traced and was wondering if there is a way to retrieve this information?  Simple example,

```
tst <- function(cond) { if (cond) 'yay' else 'neigh' }
tst1 <- function(x) { x*x }
trace('tst', tracer=browser)
trace('tst1', tracer=browser)

## Can I retrieve a vector of functions being traced?
## would like a result here to be:
## [1] "tst"  "tst1"

## Cleaning
untrace('tst')
untrace('tst1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize this, but `trace` adds a class, "functionWithTrace" to the modified functions.  So, it is easy enough to retrieve those,

```
res <- eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(x) if (inherits(x, 'functionWithTrace')) TRUE)
names(unlist(res))
# [1] "tst"  "tst1"
```